# Where do I get Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

I'd like to host Q/A application in my web site.
Where can I get source code?

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

StackExchange 1.0 was closed a long time ago in favor of Area 51. Thats where you can submit requests for any subject you want. It will take time though

http://area51.stackexchange.com

EDIT: Here's a good reason why: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/